# internal error: retry receiver class not set yet

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing a simple gcm push server notification to mobile but when I push from the server, the notification is not displayed on mobile phone. The log shows this error

> internal error: retry receiver class not set yet

Can someone tell me how to fix this or give me a link to a gcm library that fix this error. I searched on the web, google say this error is fixed in a library version but I can't find it on the net.

Comment: Did you add receiver block (name, permission and the actions) in your android Manifest!?

Comment: yes my manifest is fine. but i don't receive any notificaiton.. in my log it says sql lite fails is it a mistake ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is solved by Android-GCM team but not released yet.Check `Non-released changes (available only on source-code repository)`  [here](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/wiki/ReleaseNotes). The source code is available,you add it as library to your project.

Otherwise,simple work around to rectify this issue is, restart your Device.

Answer (score 2):

This is gcm.jar library bug.Download the latest jar file from android sdk path :

**android-sdk-windows\extras\google\gcm\gcm-client\dist**