# While starting activity the GCM is sometimes working and sometimes its not.

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

```
GCMRegistrar: internal error: retry receiver class not set yet.
```

**Why this is coming.**

*Any help would be appreciated.*

Comment: Did you register the broadcast receiver?

Comment: This can be the same issue as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952577/internal-error-retry-receiver-class-not-set-yet

Comment: Just to add that GCM will be deprecated soon. You should use FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because of using an older version of `gcm.jar`. Please use the latest versions of GCM client, which you can get from [here](https://github.com/google/gcm#git/gcm-client/dist)
Please update if it works out.

Comment: In that link where is the gcm.jar file, or do I've to use the classes instead.